# Angular Material Select default value is not getting selected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a select box in which i have binded the array of objects. I want to set a default intial value to it i.e. the 0th position value , i have tried using [(value)] and [(ngModel)] but it doesnt work. Am i missing something?

HTMl -

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="onLifeChange($event)" [(value)]="lifeId">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let life of lifeData" [value]="life">{{life?.fxlifeid}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

TS -

```
 getLives(): void {
    this.insuredService.getLives(caseId).subscribe(res => {
      this.lifeData = res;
      this.numberOfLife = this.lifeData.length;
      this.lifeId = this.lifeData[0].fxlifeid;
    })
  }
```

I am calling getLives on ngOnInit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a FormControl  object in your component.ts file

```
formCotrolName = new FormCotrol();
```

In component.html file assign this object to mat-select control

```
[formCotrol]='formCotrolName'
```

Now in your component.ts file, we get get the value from that dropdown by using formCotrol.value property. But this value property is read only. To set value we need use setValue method

```
formControl.setValue(value);
```